# How to check if the file exists in the Azure Blob Container in java

Tags: java, azure, azure-blob-storage

I want to check whether the file exists in the container of the Azure Blob Storage. If the file exists then I download the file.

Comment: Please show some code that you have written.

Comment: There is an azure storage sdk for java: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java

Answer (score 1):

Due to there not being any REST API or SDK API to check a blob whether exists, you can not directly check it. As I known, the only way to check the existence of a blob is to check the error information when getting a blob. Please refer to [`Common REST API Error Codes`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/storageservices/common-rest-api-error-codes), as below.

[image]

Here are my steps and sample code for checking the existence of a blob using [Microsoft Azure Storage SDK v10 for Java](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-java).

The [maven dependency](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage-blob) of Azure Storage SDK v10 for Java as below.

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.microsoft.azure/azure-storage-blob -->
<dependency>
    <groupId>com.microsoft.azure</groupId>
    <artifactId>azure-storage-blob</artifactId>
    <version>10.4.0</version>
</dependency>
```

1. Generate a blob url with SAS signature.

   ```
    String accountName = "<your storage account name>";
    String accountKey = "<your storage account key>";

    public String generateUrlWithSAS(String containerName, String blobName) throws InvalidKeyException {
        SharedKeyCredentials credentials = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
        ServiceSASSignatureValues values = new ServiceSASSignatureValues()
                .withProtocol(SASProtocol.HTTPS_ONLY) // Users MUST use HTTPS (not HTTP).
                .withExpiryTime(OffsetDateTime.now().plusDays(2)) // 2 days before expiration.
                .withContainerName(containerName)
                .withBlobName(blobName);
        BlobSASPermission permission = new BlobSASPermission()
                .withRead(true)
                .withAdd(true)
                .withWrite(true);
        values.withPermissions(permission.toString());
        SASQueryParameters serviceParams = values.generateSASQueryParameters(credentials);
        String sasSign = serviceParams.encode();
        return String.format(Locale.ROOT, "https://%s.blob.core.windows.net/%s/%s%s", accountName, containerName, blobName, sasSign);
    }
   ```
2. Make a HTTP `HEAD` request for the URL with SAS signature to check the response status code

   ```
    public static boolean exists(String urlWithSAS) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
        HttpURLConnection conn = (HttpURLConnection) new URL(urlWithSAS).openConnection();
        conn.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
        return conn.getResponseCode() == 200;
    }
   ```

Also, you can directly check the existence via catching the related exception while downloading a blob.

Answer (score 0):

Easier way (and less confusing to me) in case you are the blob owner, inspired by @Peter Pan's answer.

```java
boolean blobExists(String containerName, String blobName) {
    ServiceURL serviceUrl = getServiceUrl();
    HttpURLConnection httpUrlConnection = (HttpURLConnection)
        serviceUrl.createContainerURL(containerName)
            .createBlockBlobURL(blobName)
            .toURL().openConnection();
    httpUrlConnection.setRequestMethod("HEAD");
    return httpUrlConnection.getResponseCode() / 100 == 2;
}

ServiceURL getServiceUrl() {
    SharedKeyCredentials credentials = new SharedKeyCredentials(accountName, accountKey);
    return new ServiceURL(new URL(azureUrl), StorageURL.createPipeline(credentials, new PipelineOptions()));
}
```

Tested with library `com.microsoft.azure:azure-storage-blob:10.5.0`.